# SQLiteDataAdapter returns wrong column types when dataset is empty

Tags: c#, sqlite

I create a table with only column ID [INT]

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (ID int)
```

and insert an 1 into it

```
INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES (1)
```

Then I call three SELECT's who will never return a row

```
SELECT ID FROM Test1 WHERE 0 = 1  
SELECT ID + 1 as ID FROM Test1 WHERE 0 = 1  
SELECT CAST(ID as TEXT) ID FROM Test1 WHERE 0 = 1
```

and populate empty data tables using

```
SQLiteDataAdapter(Command).Fill(dtResult):
```

First query returns column ID as [Int32], second and third query return ID as [object]. I noticed that any operations (like `ID + 1` or `CAST as TEXT`) on a column cause resulting data type to be [object] instead of original data type. This happens only if query return no rows - no matter if table is empty or data never match filtering expressions. If query returns non-empty dataset then types are good for all three queries.
Is there a way to have correct types in the filled data table when using expressions and query return no rows?

Comment: "First query returns column ID as [Int32]" -> it works even with zero rows. In the other two queries, you have expressions.

Comment: Note that in sqlite, types are associated with individual *values* stored in a table, not with columns. You can store strings, blobs, floats, etc. in that "int" column.

Comment: @Tarik this is what I've said - "no matter if table is empty or data never match filtering expressions"

Comment: @Shawn why engine can correctly detect column type but not expression result type?

Comment: I assume that the result that is returned does not contain specific type info except when it's a column in which case it retrieves the column definition from the system catalog. A possible way around it is to explicitly convert `ID + 1` to int, hoping that the type info will be returned. Just speculating though.